# Uncaught Error: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Argument #7

Tags: php, mysqli

I dont know why but the prepere  `if (!$stmt->prepare($sql))` works fine. but the moment i use `$stmt->bind_param();` i got a error. The type of variables are correct, i know i dont have to use strval() but it just to be shure thats not the problem. I have searched for this for a couple of days now and i'm still stuck 

 
code:

```
 function validPost(){
            $sensorMac      = strval($_POST['mac']); 
            $sensorName     = strval($_POST['nameSensor']);
            $sensorLocation = strval($_POST['locationSensor']);
            $sensorUnitId   = intval($_POST['unitId']);
            $sensorInfo     = strval( $_POST["infoSensor"]);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO sensor ( mac, name, location, info, unitID, user_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($GLOBALS['conn']);

            if (!$stmt->prepare($sql)) {
                header("location: /webservices/sensor/add-sensor.php?show=stmt");
                exit();
            }

            $stmt->bind_param("ssssii", $sensorMac, $sensorName , $sensorLocation, $sensorInfo , $sensorUnitId, intval($_SESSION['userId']));   
            
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
}
```

the error i got:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Argument #7 cannot be passed by reference in D:\webpage\webservices\sensor\add-sensor.php:40
Stack trace:
#0 D:\webpage\webservices\sensor\add-sensor.php(74): validPost()
#1 {main}
  thrown in D:\webpage\webservices\sensor\add-sensor.php on line 40
```

This is the database is use:
[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr2SZ.png)

Comment: Shouldnt it be `$mysqli -> stmt_init()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bind_param() function requires that all the arguments after the types argument are passed by reference.

But your argument #7 is:

```
intval($_SESSION['userId'])
```

This is not an lvalue. It is not a variable from which you can take a reference.

In other words, you can't do this:

```
intval($_SESSION['userId']) = 12345; // ERROR
```

So you must make a variable:

```
$userId = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssii", $sensorMac, $sensorName, $sensorLocation,
  $sensorInfo, $sensorUnitId, $userId);
```

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("ssssii", $sensorMac, $sensorName , $sensorLocation, $sensorInfo , $sensorUnitId, intval($_SESSION['userId']));   will work fine. !!!!

Comment: @Bil Your explanation seems to be wrong!

Comment: @IndraKumarS If you have a different solution, I encourage you to test it, then post an answer.

Comment: i am not talking about a different solution. I tested it in PHP 7.4.5 intval($_SESSION["somekey"]) works fine with bind param

Comment: I also tested it, and my test throws the same error: _"Argument #2 cannot be passed by reference"_. How do you suggest solving these errors?

Comment: May i know your php version

Comment: I tested on PHP 8.0.7 but this has been true in all past versions of mysqli. This error has been [reported many times](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com+bind_param+Argument+cannot+be+passed+by+reference&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvkdi9qanxAhWMjp4KHRmVCX4QgwN6BAgIEAE&biw=1709&bih=1226), and the solution is always to create a variable so you can pass it by reference. Arguments passed by reference must be variables or references, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php